# Допускается ли передача информации о добавляемом элементе от модели к представлению через событие? (MVC)

Tags: mvc

Такой вопрос, в модель добавляется элемент, модель оповещает представление о том, что был добавлен элемент. Допускается ли передача информации о элементе от модели к представлению через событие, или представление должно сама получить данные?

Необходимо лишь частично менять представление, а не заново рендерить все.

UPD
Под событием я подразумеваю оповещение через обсервер.

Спасибо.

Comment: это какой-то абстрактный теоретический вопрос? или применимо к каким-то конкретным технологиям?

Comment: Это абстрактный вопрос, если писать mvc с нуля без каких-либо фреймворков. Вообще пишу в JavaScript-html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да правильно, хотя чаще для этого используют MVVM фреймворки, но если речь идет о достаточно простой странице, то можно обойтись использованием Partial View.

Приведу пример на C# MVC:

```
<div>
  <p>Some content</p>
  <div id="myPartialViewContainer">
      @Html.Partial("_FeaturedProduct")
  </div>
  <div>Some other content</div>
</div>
```

Вышеописанная конструкция является контейнером для части вьюхи. Ее мы можем перезагрузить отдельно с помощью скрипта:

```
$(function(){
   $('#activelist,#inactivelist').change(function () {
      var id="someval"; 
      var status = 'inactive';
      $("#myPartialViewContainer").load('@Url.Action("Skits","KitSection")' + '?id=' + id+ '&status=' + status)
  });
});
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, вопрос не о технической возможности (технически-то возможно практически всё), а о правильности с точки зрения паттерна MVC.

Comment: @VladD ну не отвечать же просто "да, правильно" :)